# merge data frame with repeated observations

Tags: r, merge, dplyr

I have two data frames:

```
df1 <- data.frame(index = c(rep(2,5), rep(3,8), rep(4,6), rep(5,9)),
              start = c(0:4, 0:7, 0:5, 0:8),
              end = c(1:5, 1:8, 1:6, 1:9),
              v1= rep(1,28))


df2 <- data.frame(index = c(rep(2,5), rep(3,7), rep(4,6), rep(5,6)),
              v1 = rnorm(24))
```

Assume the `index` column represents the different observations of a person.
In this example in `df1` we have a person with id 2 and 5 observations,
a person with id 3 has 8 observations and so on.

I now want to replace the values of `v1` in `df1` by the values of `v1` in `df2`. df2 has sometimes fewer observations than df1, e.g. for persons 3 and 5.

Merging should be in a way that the v1's of df2 are taken for the first observations and if no more observations are available then `NA`s should be replaced.

The structure of the df1 frame should be preserved, except that the v1's should be replaced with that from df2.

Comment: How do you know which rows in the first dataset to put the info from the second dataset on?  Is it just based on the order of the dataset (so any NA at the end of the group)?

Comment: @aosmith exactly, NAs should be at the end of each group,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this via a join, you'd need a within-group index so you have an unique identifier to match on.

This is straightforward to create if `df2` is already in the correct order and so any NA values after joining should be at the end of each group.  You can add an `end` variable to `df2` and the join on `index` and `end`.

I also remove `v1` from the first dataset, `df1`.

```
library(dplyr)
df2 %>%
    group_by(index) %>%
    mutate(end = 1:n()) %>%
    left_join(select(df1, -v1), .)

   index start end          v1
1      2     0   1 -1.57254316
2      2     1   2 -1.09000063
3      2     2   3 -0.13775401
4      2     3   4 -0.94088741
5      2     4   5  0.45180766
6      3     0   1  2.14925746
7      3     1   2  1.79103360
8      3     2   3 -0.28344963
9      3     3   4 -0.10250375
10     3     4   5  0.21321949
11     3     5   6  0.07982287
12     3     6   7  0.37987963
13     3     7   8          NA
14     4     0   1  0.41360521
15     4     1   2 -0.28888575
16     4     2   3 -0.58786830
17     4     3   4  0.14340062
18     4     4   5  1.46434162
19     4     5   6  1.73668914
20     5     0   1  1.43112233
21     5     1   2  0.40772442
22     5     2   3 -1.77085141
23     5     3   4 -0.94653948
24     5     4   5 -1.54412791
25     5     5   6 -0.28174510
26     5     6   7          NA
27     5     7   8          NA
28     5     8   9          NA
```

As pointed out in the comments by @SteveBeaupre, you could replace my old habit of `1:n()` with `row_number()`.

Comment: You could replace `1:n()` by `row_number()`

Comment: @StevenBeaupré because more typing is for some reason better?

Comment: @eddi Not *better* but perhaps more *idiomatic* ?

Comment: @StevenBeaupré I don't know what that means here, or what the value of that is. From my seat it simply looks like more letters with no other value added, and in fact value subtracted since one now has to spend time to memorise a new function (and this is a general beef I have with all of `dplyr`).

Comment: @eddi Yes I get your point. `data.table` `1:.N` and the `dplyr` equivalent `1:n()` is perfectly fine. I think the idea behind `row_number()` to assign unique numbers to each row within the partition might be to mimic the `SQL` behavior.

Comment: For example `translate_sql(group_by(x) %>% mutate(y = 1:n()))` gives *Error in from:to : NA/NaN argument In addition: Warning message: In escape(from:to) : NAs introduced by coercion* - And would not work on a database - `translate_sql(group_by(x) %>% mutate(y = row_number()))` gives `<SQL> GROUP_BY("x") > MUTATE(ROW_NUMBER() AS "y")` and would work.